# How to upgrade this small code from Extjs3 to Extjs4.2?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs3, extjs4.2

I have been trying to find a solution to upgrading the code below from `ExtJs3.4` to `ExtJs 4.2`? 
I found some answers and looked into Sencha's docs, but still having hard time with it.

If anyone knows how to rewrite this code in ExtJs4.2, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

```
        var config = 
        {       
            store: new Ext.data.Store({
                autoLoad: true,
                proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({ url: '/main/...' }),
                reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader
                ({
                    root: 'data',
                    totalProperty: 'totalCount',
                    id: 'id',
                    fields: 
                    [
                        'alert_id',
                        {name: 'duration', type: 'int'},
                        {name: 'start_date', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'timestamp'},
                        {name: 'end_date', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'timestamp'},
                        'monitor'
                    ]
                })
            }),
        }

        // more code here
```

This is what I know from the code above:

- `Models` are using the `field` not `Stores` anymore
- `reader` should be inside the `proxy`

These are the warning

```
[DEPRECATED][4.0][Ext.data.Store]: Passing a "fields" config via the store's reader config is no longer supported. Instead you should configure a model and pass it as the store's "model" config. Please see the header docs for Ext.data.Store for details on properly setting up your data components.
ext-all.js (line 21)
[DEPRECATED][4.0][Ext.data.Store] reader (config): The reader config should now be specified on the configured proxy rather than directly on the store.
```

---

**Addendum**

I was doing it this way at first:

```
 Ext.define('User', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     id: 'id',
     fields: 
     [
         'alert_id',
         {name: 'duration', type: 'int'},
         {name: 'start_date', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'timestamp'},
         {name: 'end_date', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'timestamp'},
         'monitor'
     ]
 });

 var config = 
 {      
      store: new Ext.data.Store({
          model:'User',
          proxy: 
          {
              url: '/main/...',
              reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader
              ({
                    root: 'data',
                    totalProperty: 'totalCount',
              })
          }

      }),

      // more code here
 }
```

So I was not sure what to write instead of `reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader`.

Also whether to use the `Model` or not since `Store` was not using `fields` anymore. 
I had no idea about `Ext.data.JsonStore` until I saw the answer.

Comment: I voted down because it doesn't show enough effort, did you look at the upgrade documentation? http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-3-to-4-migration/

Comment: @JuanMendes What is your problem? You are not answering to the question anyways, just leave it alone. 

FYI, for smart asses like you, look at the last part of my question. How do you think i got the error `[DEPRECATED][4.0][Ext.data.Store]: Passing a "fields"...` ???.
That is because I am using the migration guide ;)

Comment: My problem is with people who ask questions without doing enough research. Your error message is clear, fields should be on the proxy now. If you look up  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json You'll see a clear example of the correct usage. My downvote still stands, you're asking others to do your work for you before reallty trying http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ I'll gladly take my downvote if you show what you've tried, every question should show what you've tried, as it stands, you've tried nothing.

Comment: ok, I will add what I tried, but it was not correct.

Comment: With your new edit, it's easier to understand which part you weren't getting, I added some explanation as to how it should be done in Ext 4, and also suggested the minimum changes that still work with Ext 4. Hope you're not mad at me anymore, my only intent with my downvotes is to improve questions and answers so they can be useful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris Farmer's answer is correct. However, here's a more thorough explanation.

Ext now encourages you to document the format of your data, so you should use an `Ext.data.Model` to define the field names. The suggested way to do it, is to define the proxy on the model itself so it can be loaded independent of a store

```
// File 1
Ext.define('my.User', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: [
         'alert_id',
         {name: 'duration', type: 'int'},
         {name: 'start_date', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'timestamp'},
         {name: 'end_date', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'timestamp'},
         'monitor'
     ],
     proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/main/...',
        // Reader is now on the proxy, as the message was explaining
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        }
     }
 });

 // File 2
 // Use the model with the store
 var config = {
     // Passing the model definition to the store as the message was explaining
     store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({model:  'my.User', autoLoad: true})
 };
```

Ext still allows you to use fields definitions instead of models when creating stores, but it's not recommended, an implicit model will be created. Here's how to do it.

```
 var config = {
     store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
         fields: [
             'alert_id',
             {name: 'duration', type: 'int'},
             {name: 'start_date', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'timestamp'},
             {name: 'end_date', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'timestamp'},
             'monitor'
         ],
         proxy: {
             type: 'ajax',
             url: '/main/...',
             reader: {
                 type: 'json',
                 root: 'data',
                 totalProperty: 'totalCount'
             }
         }
     });
 };
```

Comment: +1, using a model is certainly better practice. Under the hood an anonymous model is created if you use `fields: []` inline on the store.

Comment: @A.S.Roma Your last edit is not required, you can pass the constructor if you want, you have to pass a string if you're doing dynamic loading

Comment: I cannot figure out why? but `model` does not work. When I use the second version, it works. How do I know? firebug shows php response in the second case, nothing with the first??? do you know why?

Comment: Maybe your other class is not loaded? [This example shows](http://jsfiddle.net/VzBek/1/) that if the class is loaded, you can pass its constructor.  Why don't you step through it and see if that class is undefined at that point? However, there's nothing wrong with passing the string name, it's just that my IDE will spot if I pass a constructor that hasn't been defined, whereas if I pass a string, it doesn't know...

Answer (score 2):

How about this?  The `JsonStore` is documented at http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore.

```
initComponent: function () {

    var config = {
        store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: [ 'alert_id', 'duration', 'start_date', 'end_date' ],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '/main/...',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data',
                    totalProperty: 'totalCount'
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
initComponent: function () {

this.store= new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: [ 'alert_id', 'duration', 'start_date', 'end_date' ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/main/...',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data',
                totalProperty: 'totalCount'
            }
        }
    });

 this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is the same as `@Chris Farmer` answer

Comment: In this you are not setting the store to another config var, you can just use this.store and call this.callparent after store definition

Comment: @objectone But it's essentially the same answer, consider deleting it